# Android NDK, No rule to make target

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I've seen this question other places, but the answers don't seem to apply to my situation.  I've got a .cpp file (not a .c file).  I'm getting the error:

make: *** No rule to make target `jni/native.c', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/native/native.o'.  Stop. Cirapi_android          C/C++ Problem

Here's my Android.mk file (very simple):

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS:=-llog
LOCAL_MODULE:=native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=native.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I've removed all the extra spaces that solved other's problems.  It's complaining about native.c which I don't even have listed in my makefile.  Any ideas?

I'm on MacOSX Snow Leopard, Eclipse Juno, NDK r8

Comment: Do you have an `extern "C"{}` inside `native.cpp`?

Comment: Yes I do. The cpp file compiles fine within Eclipse.  I'm wondering if there's a paths or permissions issue.  I had to specify the absolute path for Eclipse to find the jni.h header file.

Answer (score 17):

Got it to work...not sure what the key was...changed the makefile to..

```
TOP_LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)  

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS:=-llog
LOCAL_MODULE:=native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=native.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

...also removed the .o files from the obj directory...suspected that a clean was not working correctly.

Comment: deleting all files in the obj directory did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: How do you get to the obj directory?

Comment: 9 years later, deleting the obj directory saved me hours of work. Thanks!